# Handle event after DismissOverlayView (Android Wear)

Tags: android, events, wear-os

Is it possible to handle some finishing stuffs when user press the X button in DismissOverlayView? Like save some files, etc.

Alternatively, I would like to pause the app before the X button and resume if X is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it would call your Activity's onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() methods, which is normally where you handle the things you mentioned such as saving data. You should take a look at Android's [Activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), which also applies to Android Wear. In particular, here's what it says about onPause(): "Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc." Sounds like what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This is if the user press the X button (then onDestroy should be called). What if the user does not press the X button? Any idea whether I can do anything in some functions?

Comment: Right. I'm not sure if there is a way to know if/when the user doesn't press it. On the other hand, I don't really see why it would be necessary; your app should keep running as normal even if the X is showing, until they click on it. That way, if they don't click on it, your app is still behaving the same as before they long-pressed.

Comment: I give you a scenario: I wrote a game which I wish to PAUSE when the user long press, if the user does not exit, I would like to UNPAUSE and continue with the game.

Comment: Can you check if it calls onPause() and onResume() in that case?

Comment: I don't think either is called. Everything happened as usual behind the X button.

Comment: I'm not sure, then. I might try to play around with it if I get a chance. Let me know if you figure out a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

This will get the event of selecting around the edge of the DismissOverlayView:

```
    DismissOverlayView dismissOverlayView = (DismissOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.dismiss_overlay);
    dismissOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("Cancelled DismissOverlayView");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```